# Deploy Django REST API to api.example.com: Apache 2.2, mod_wsgi and mod_rewrite

Tags: django, mod-rewrite, django-rest-framework, subdomain

I have been searching for information on this topic for a couple days and I keep running into road blocks.

I have a Django web site and application running at `www.example.com` and I'm forcing HTTPS. It's deployed on Apache 2.2 with WSGI. This works fine and works for both `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

I also have a REST API (`pip install djangorestframework`) running at `https://www.example.com/api/v1/`. This also works fine.

I want to run the API from a subdomain `https://api.example.com` and keep this URL in the address bar. For example, to fetch JSON objects I might use something like this:

```
curl -X GET https://api.example.com/objects/ -H 'Authorization: Token xxx'
```

I can get this now by using this:

```
curl -X GET https://www.example.com/api/v1/objects/ -H 'Authorization: Token xxx'
```

I have a separate SSL certificate for this subdmain and his has been correctly configured.

I have tried many things in my Apache configuration to accomplish this but failed at every turn. I thought I could use `mod_rewrite` to silently fetch the content from `https://www.example.com/api/v1/` while leaving `https://api.example.com` in the address bar. Is this possible? Here is what I've tried (in the `sites-available` virtual host file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/api/v1/$1 [L]
```

I have tried several variations of this idea to no avail. I played around with `HTTPS on/off` as well with no real benefit.

I read a couple places that using `mod_proxy` could accomplish this but when I went down this road, the API was available (after quite a bit of tweaking) at the desired URL (`https://api.example.com`) but none of my static content was there and when I clicked on a relative link in the Django REST Framework UI, I'd get 404s because it was looking at:

`https://api.example.com/api/v1/`

which Django complained about: `/api/v1/api/v1/`

I guess all I'm trying to do is make `https://api.example.com` the base URL for the API as if it were `https://www.example.com/api/v1/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate that lead to the discovery of the `django-hosts` package:

[Django subdomain configuration for API endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433536/django-subdomain-configuration-for-api-endpoints?noredirect=1#comment47797946_28433536)

I have been playing around with this and it shows promise, although I haven't "solved" my problem yet. I plan to edit this answer once I get more information to share. In the meantime, if anyone has used `django-hosts` to approach my original question, please add your answers here or at least make some comments!